# Editor and projections ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-10.0, coordinate-system, standard-license-level

When opening an edit session Arc is telling me that some of my shape files' coordinate systems do not match the data frame.

Here is the data frame coordinate system:

> Stereo_70
>
> Projection: Double_Stereographic
>
> False_Easting: 500000.000000
>
> False_Northing: 500000.000000
>
> Central_Meridian: 25.000000
>
> Scale_Factor: 0.999750
>
> Latitude_Of_Origin: 46.000000
>
> Linear Unit: Meter
>
> GCS_Dealul_Piscului_1970
>
> Datum: D_Dealul_Piscului_1970

And here is the coordinate system that all the shape files in question have:

> Projected Coordinate System:  Stereo_70
>
> Projection:   Double_Stereographic
>
> False_Easting:    500000.00000000
>
> False_Northing:   500000.00000000
>
> Longitude_Of_Origin:  25.00000000
>
> Scale_Factor: 0.99975000
>
> Latitude_Of_Origin:   46.00000000
>
> Linear Unit:  Meter
>
> Geographic Coordinate System:  GCS_Dealul_Piscului_1970
>
> Datum:    D_Dealul_Piscului_1970
>
> Prime Meridian:   Greenwich
>
> Angular Unit:     Degree

Now is it just me or is anyone else having difficulty seeing the difference?  Doe this mean I'm going to have to reproject the files in question FROM their original projection, TO their original projection?  I'm not even sure that's possible but will try now.

And short of that I guess I just wipe the projections and define them again.

Comment: ArcMap is terribly stupid in this case. It always looks at the name of the projection, not at the actual parameters. I either ignore this error, or use the `define projection` tool to define the projection of all layers to one projection.

Comment: Thanks Devdatta.  I don't mind if it points out that I forgot to project something.  That's quite useful.  But this is... well... rubbish :)  I shall define away.  Thanks again.

Comment: I've often faced this problem when data comes from other software. That software might use the correct parameters for say UTM 43N, but the name is not what ArcGIS expects. And all ArcMap can do, it to throw this Warning.

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe could you add this as an answer? I agree it is quite terrible, and one would not be inclined to think that something so simple is the cause.

Comment: Slightly less rigorous but quicker than "define projection" I think, I just went into catalog, selected the properties for the shapefiles and altered (well, not altered at all really) the projections there.  Editor is now satisfied in ArcMap.  Nothing like making a workflow easier.

Comment: @OliverBurdekin: What you have done is pretty much the same thing. The `Define Projection` tool, is just a way of doing that very thing via geoprocessing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the strange Limitations of ArcMap, is that it only looks at the name of the projection, and doesn't actually check the parameters, if the name is different.

I've often faced this problem when data comes from other software. That software might use the correct parameters for say UTM 43N, but the name is not what ArcGIS expects. And all ArcMap can do, it to throw this Warning.

In this case you have two options, both equally good:

- Just ignore the warning.
- Use the [Define Projection](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000077000000) tool, and set the projection of the problematic layer to the projection that ArcGIS expects. (Note: that I am talking about the `Define Projection` tool, and not the `Project` tool). This tool will just reset the coordinate system, and will not touch the coordinates. This option might involve more work, but you won't face the warning again in the future.